# Place Pip and Yolk inside or outside a virtual environment?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, yolk

I'm using `virtualenv` for sandboxing my Python environment, `pip` to install/uninstall packages and `yolk` to list the packages.

I can install packages to my virtual environment by using `pip install <package name> -e=<environment name>` and I guess I don't need to have `pip` inside my virtual environment. Am i correct?

If I need to list out all the installed packages in my virtual environment, can I use `yolk -l` to do so? I know I can do this by keeping `yolk` installed inside the environment but is this also possible by keeping `yolk` outside the environment i.e. the global Python installation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your workflow:

1. Add virtualenv and pip to your global environment.
2. Create virtualenvs
3. Within a virtualenv, add new packages

I recommend you look into [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/). It makes the maintenance of virtualenvs way easier.

1. Download and install virtualenvwrapper in your global environment
2. Create directory ~/.virtualenvs
3. Modify your ~/.bashrc with these statements:

   export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
   export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS='--no-site-packages --python=python2.6'
   source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

Then you can create, delete, modify, and change between virtualenvs easily.

So, for your questions:

1. Should I put `pip` inside my virtualenv?

   > No, do not do that.
2. Should I use `yolk` to list the packages?

   > Not familiar with `yolk`. I just use `pip freeze` and then I get a
   >   requirements file that lists all the packages for recreating my
   >   environment.